# How does one justify Schwartz's answer to his problem 3.7 in "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory, variational-calculus

In problem 3.7 of his textbook "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model", Schwartz gives a simplified Lagrangian density

$$
\mathcal{L}=- \frac{1}{2} h \Box h + \epsilon^a h^2 \Box h -\epsilon^b h T
$$

(where $\Box \equiv \partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}$) and states that the implied equations of motion for the field $h$ are "roughly"
$$
\Box h  = \epsilon^a  \Box  h^2 - \epsilon^b  T
$$
(where my $\epsilon$ is notation for his "Planck scale", $M_{\mathrm{Pl}}$). I've tried to derive this equation of motion, as follows.

The first step is to restore the tensor indices, but here the term $h^2 \Box h$ presents a puzzle, because its tensor form has to evaluate as a Lorentz invariant. The tempting expression $h_{\mu\nu} h_{\mu\nu} (\partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu})$ doesn't work (we have indices featuring thrice, and the outcome is not an invariant). As a clue, we can go back to Schwartz's original Lagrangian density (stated at the outset of his problem 3.7), and assume what is required is

$$
h^2 \Box h \rightarrow (\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu})(\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\alpha})h_{\nu\beta}
$$
in which every index features exactly twice (and $h$ appears to the third degree). Accepting this, we have
$$
\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{2} h_{\mu\nu} \partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu} + \epsilon^a (\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu})(\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\alpha})h_{\nu\beta}  - \epsilon^b h_{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu} .
$$
Now we need to evaluate the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial h_{pq}} = \partial_{\gamma} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_{\gamma} h_{pq})}
$$
where $h_{pq}$ is one (arbitrary) component of the tensor.

The left hand side (LHS) is
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial h_{pq}} = - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{p\mu} \delta_{q\nu} \Box h_{\mu\nu} + \epsilon^a \partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu} \partial_{\beta} h_{\mu\alpha} \delta_{\nu p}\delta_{\beta q} - \epsilon^b T_{\mu\nu} \delta_{p \mu} \delta_{q \nu}
= - \frac{1}{2} \Box h_{pq} + \epsilon^a  \partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu p} \partial_{\beta} h_{\mu\alpha} \delta_{\beta q} - \epsilon^b T_{pq}
= - \frac{1}{2} \Box h_{pq} + \epsilon^a  \partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu p} \partial_{q} h_{\mu\alpha} - \epsilon^b T_{pq} .
$$

Next, note that only the second term in the Lagrangian density will contribute to the RHS of the Euler-Lagrange equation, since it alone contains terms in $\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu}$. Ignoring for the moment the factor $\epsilon^a$,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_{\gamma} h_{pq})} (\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu})(\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\alpha})h_{\nu\beta} = (\partial_{\alpha}  h_{\mu\nu})  h_{\nu\beta}  \delta_{\gamma \beta} \delta_{\mu p} \delta_{\alpha q}    +  (\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\alpha}) h_{\nu\beta}  \delta_{\alpha \gamma} \delta_{\mu p} \delta_{\nu q}
= (\partial_{\alpha}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \beta }  \delta_{\gamma \beta}  \delta_{\alpha q}    +   (\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu \gamma}) h_{\nu\beta}  \delta_{\mu p} \delta_{\nu q}
= (\partial_{\alpha}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \gamma }  \delta_{\alpha q}   +   (\partial_{\beta}h_{p \gamma}) h_{\nu\beta}  \delta_{\nu q}
= (\partial_{q}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \gamma }    +   (\partial_{\beta}h_{p \gamma}) h_{q \beta}
= (\partial_{q}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \gamma }    +   (\partial_{\mu}h_{p \gamma}) h_{q \mu}
$$
and now taking the partial derivative $\partial/\partial_{\gamma}$ of this
$$
\partial_{\gamma} \frac{\partial}{\partial (\partial_{\gamma} h_{pq})} (\partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu\nu})(\partial_{\beta}h_{\mu\alpha})h_{\nu\beta} = (\partial_{\gamma} \partial_{q}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \gamma } +  (\partial_{q}  h_{p \nu}) \, (\partial_{\gamma} h_{\nu \gamma })   +   (\partial_{\gamma }\partial_{\mu} h_{p \gamma}) h_{q \mu}  + (\partial_{\mu}h_{p \gamma}) (\partial_{\gamma}h_{q \mu})  .
$$
This, upon multiplication by $\epsilon^a$, is the RHS of the Euler-Lagrange equation. So finally, the Euler-Lagrange equation produces the equation of motion:

$$- \frac{1}{2} \Box h_{pq} + \epsilon^a  \partial_{\alpha} h_{\mu p} \partial_{q} h_{\mu\alpha} - \epsilon^b T_{pq} =  \epsilon^a \left[ (\partial_{\gamma} \partial_{q}  h_{p \nu})  h_{\nu \gamma } +  (\partial_{q}  h_{p \nu})  (\partial_{\gamma} h_{\nu \gamma })   + (\partial_{\gamma }\partial_{\mu} h_{p \gamma}) h_{q \mu} + (\partial_{\mu} h_{p \gamma}) (\partial_{\gamma}h_{q \mu}) \right]$$

**Question: If this derivation is correct, how is it to be reconciled with Schwartz's "rough" result?**

**Note added in response to Andrew's suggestion**: if we take $h$ as being a scalar field, a parallel set of (simpler) steps leads to the following equation of motion:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \Box h = \epsilon^a \Box h^2 - 2\epsilon^a (\partial_{\alpha} h) (\partial_{\alpha} h) - \epsilon^b T .
$$
This roughly matches Professor Schwartz's result if we neglect the $(\partial h)^2$ term on the right hand side, and if only magnitudes are of interest, the extra $\frac{1}{2}$ on the left can be neglected.

**Solving for for the field $h$**

Simplifying Schwartz's (dimensionless) equation to
$$
\Box h = \epsilon \Box h^2 - \epsilon T
$$
with $\epsilon \ll 1$ and given that $T=m \delta^3(x)$, we have
$$
\nabla^2 h = \epsilon \nabla^2 h^2 + \epsilon T
$$

Now represent $h$ by way of a perturbation expansion in the small parameter
$$
h = h_0 + \epsilon h_1 + \epsilon^2 h_2+... 
$$
so that
$$
h^2 = h_0^2 + 2 \epsilon h_0 h_1 + \epsilon^2 h_1^2 + ...
$$
Substituting we have
$$
\nabla^2 \left(h_0 + \epsilon h_1 + \epsilon^2 h_2+... \right)  =  \epsilon \nabla^2 \left( h_0^2 + 2 \epsilon h_0 h_1 + \epsilon^2 h_1^2 + ... \right) + \epsilon T
$$

Matching powers:
$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon^0 &: \nabla^2 h_0 = 0 \\
\epsilon^1 &: \nabla^2 h_1 = \nabla^2 h_0^2 + T \\
\epsilon^2 &: \nabla^2 h_2 = 2 \nabla^2 h_0 h_1 \\
\epsilon^3 &: \nabla^2 h_3 = \nabla^2 h_1^2
\end{align}
$$

To lowest order in $\epsilon$ we have $\nabla^2 h_0 = \nabla \cdot \nabla h_0 = 0$, or $-k^2 \widetilde{h}_0 = 0$ (where $\widetilde{h}_0$ is the Fourier transform). Inverting $\widetilde{h}_0 = 0$ gives us $h_0(r)=0$. It's interesting, though, to integrate directly. As nothing in the problem statement provides any preferred direction, we assume spherical symmetry, thus the Laplacian operator reduces to
$$
\nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left[r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \right]
$$
Then from $\nabla^2 h_0=0$ with the requirement that $h_0$ vanish at $r=\infty$, we get $h_0 = \alpha/r$... which unless we can justify choosing $\alpha=0$, will pop an unwanted non-zero term $\nabla^2 h_0^2 = 2 \alpha r^{-4}$ into the equation for $h_1$. Why should $\alpha=0$? Perhaps it suffices to note that $h_0$ is "unforced"... its governing equation is homogeneous.

Accepting this, then at the next order $\nabla^2 h_1 = m \delta^3(x)$ and taking the Fourier transform, $-k^2  \widetilde{h}_1 = m$. To within a factor of $(-1)$ this is the problem solved in Schwartz's Sec.~(3.4.2), so we can jump to the solution:
$$
h_1 =  - \frac{m}{4 \pi r}
$$

Provided we've chosen $h_0=0$, the next term also satisfies $\nabla^2 h_2 = 0$ and so (with no stronger justification than given for $h_0=0$) again we may choose $h_2=0$. Then
$$
\nabla^2 h_3 = \nabla^2 h_1^2 = \nabla^2 \frac{m^2}{(4 \pi r)^2} = \frac{2 m^2}{(4 \pi)^2 r^4}
$$
so that $h_3$ will be non-zero. Direct integration gives
$$
h_3 = \frac{m^2}{(4 \pi r)^2} + \frac{\beta}{r}
$$
where $\beta$ is a constant of integration that can be set to zero, on the requirement that $\partial h_3/\partial r \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$. Thus the field is given by:
$$
h \approx \epsilon \frac{-m}{4 \pi r} + \epsilon^3 \frac{m^2}{(4 \pi r)^2}
$$

Comment: (a) I'm pretty sure Schwartz's rough result amounts to treating $h$ as if it were a scalar. You should always understand this case first because when you put indicies on you should get the same answer (at least schematically), unless you had some special cancellation arising from the tensor structure.

Comment: (b) There are many more possible contractions that would give you something like $h^2 \square h$. Some examples (where indices are raised/lowered with the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$)... $h^\mu_\mu h^\nu_\nu \square h^\lambda_\lambda$, $h_{\mu\nu} h^{\mu\nu} \square h^\lambda_\lambda$, $\partial_\mu h^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu h^\lambda_\lambda$... The easiest method to derive the right set of cubic terms, is to write all of them with arbitrary coefficients and compute the E-L equations. Then compare with the Einstein tensor expanded to second order in $h$ and match the coefficients.